# what is the difference between exsol and xsim package?

Tags: exam, exercises, exsheets, tasks, xsim

what is the difference between exsol and xsim  package? And which is the closest one to exam document class?

Comment: http://www.mychemistry.eu/2017/02/improving-exsheets/ useful link